# iOS not updating JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I was updating my internal website.
I have a folder that has images and a folder that has javascript files.

I was updating the javascript files on the server and testing on my desktop and everything was fine.

I went to look at the website on my iPhone and the updates weren't there.
I used web inspector on my mac to see what the issue is, when I went to the resources tab in the developer console and had a look at the js file it was the old one that didnt contain the changes. How do I force my iphone to get the new js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your cache by going to `Settings > Safari > Clear History & Website Data`. This will remove all the history, cookies, and caches for web views (including Safari) on your device. If you'd rather not nuke *everything*, you can go to `Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data` and swipe left on a specific URL to delete all cookies and caches stored by that specific site

Comment: This worked! Is there a way from the website side I can make it always load a certain file so I don't have to do this every time I make a change?